# Are there any decentralized local exchanges for euro/usd to ether?

Tags: dapps, exchanges, localbitcoins

Is it possible to have something like a DApp to find the closest Ether owner to purchase or sell ether?

Something that can be used as a decentralized market.

Comment: Yes, it is possible if you are able to bring all the `ETH` owners to a platform, say your `DApp`.

Comment: @NikhilM If you have an answer, please post it below. Answers cannot be vetted from comments. Thanks.

Comment: @RobertCartaino sure, but i dont think i can provide a detailed answer on this. Hence commented. Am i violating something?

Comment: @NikhilM Yes. It goes against why (and how) everything is vetted on Stack Exchange. If you cannot provide a detailed answer, a comment cannot  be edited to fix that. Comments cannot be down-voted if they are wrong; or edited to correct that. They aren't ranked for correctness. And when new users see "answers" posted prominently right there below the question, we're teaching them to do the same same, and soon questions start going unanswered when the issue looks pretty much resolved... in comments. Bottom line, comments aren't answers; answers are answers.

Comment: @RobertCartaino okay got it .. thanks for pointing it out.

Answer (score 3):

It is possible to create a decentralised broker Dapp (it helps buyers and sellers find each other, but does not take part in the transactions and does not bear settlement risk).

Creating a decentralised market where USD or EUR or other non-ethereum currencies are involved, requires trusted escrow(s), who accept participants money in USD and EUR and promise only to release to another party at a signal from the Dapp. Or alternatively it requires trusted gateways (like in Ripple) that convert USD and EUR to equivalent tokens on the blockchain and back.
Trust towards an escrow or a gateway is not the only concern. Escrow and gateway operators themselves are exposed to the risk of fraud from the market participants, because USD or EUR bank transfers or credit card payments can be reversed, if a fraudster claims to himself being defrauded.